# IBM Worklight app fails to run in Xcode

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I have built a simple app using jQuery Mobile on IBM Worklight. This app works fine on IBM Mobile Browser Simulator, Android Emulator and Android smartphones.

When I copy the iPhone generated zipped project to Mac to run it in Xcode, the following errors show up when building.

[image]

Software Details:

- Worklight 5.0.5/6
- Eclipse Indigo 3.7
- Mac OS X 10.7.3
- Xcode 4.3.2

I have also set up Worklight 5.06 on Mac OS X 10.7.3 seperately which has Xcode 4.3.2. I followed IBM docs to set up Worklight on Mac. My sample app works fine on IBM Mobile browser Simulator. But application fails to run on Android Emulator,Real Android Devices and Iphone native simulator.
[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/56xlqvwmfqh75a0/l8Xj5FzbEE) are the logs and screen shots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied my project in a Mac which has Xcode 4.6 and it works fine. [Worklight iOS guides](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html) should mention clearly that the required minimum version of Xcode is 4.5, It will save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I strongly suggest upgrade to Xcode 4.6 and try with the iOS 5 or iOS 6 simulators. IBM Worklight does not support iOS 4.

Some things to try:

1. Delete the iphone\native folder
2. Build All and Deploy
3. Again take the zip file from the iphone\package folder; Extract this zip file in your Mac machine; Open the Xcode project in Xcode and run it.

   - Make sure that you build the Worklight project, and not the CordovaLib project (as can be seen in your screenshot) - click on it and choose the correct project to build.

Comment: I Select the Actual project (Name is HelloWorldIphone in my case) to start building. but it automatically builds CordovaLib first and ends up at the above screen with build errors.

Comment: Have you tried after following my suggestion with the native folder? i Also suggest upgradeing to Xcode 4.6 (it is a free upgrade).

Comment: I am unable to delete iphone/native folder. It pops an error "could not delete native folder". However, I checked the workspace, native folder has been deleted from there. Now when I choose build all and deploy, Worklight shows buildExcepetion on Log "Could not found info.plist in iphone environment" and Iphone environment is no more available in Mobile browser Console.

Comment: Refreshed and also tried after restarting eclipse; Still cant delete native folder and iphone build fails. How Can i get Iphone Environment back on IBM console ????

Comment: Calm down. Is this on Mac or Windows? If you can't delete something, it means that it is opened elsewhere. Make sure Xcode is closed, make sure the folder is closed, try deleting. Maybe something in the OS is hung, try logging off and on from your user

Comment: i managed to delete native folder after restarting my system. Then i choosed 'build all and deploy'. After copying the zipped folder from iphone/package to Mac, Exactly same issues came up as shown in above screenshot. Idan, I highly appreciate your help. I cant upgrade to xcode 4.6 because it only runs on OS X Mountain Lion 10.8+ and upgarding to Mountain Lion is not free.I am using Windows right now.  I will upgrade to Mac 10.7.5 and Xcode 4.5.2 which supports iOS 6 also. Lets see if these issues vanish after upgrading if this is really the cause.